# How to control BLDC motor in DRV10983 driver to STM32G030F6P6 controller?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, stm32cubemx, keil, stm32g

Am using in STM32G030F6P6 controller. I use DRV10983 driver IC to control BLDC fan motor. I am new to this driver IC. Can anyone help me know to How to use this DRV10983 Driver IC and communicate with STM32G030F6P6?

I have using code generate for CubeMx software. And I send the motor command data for I2C communication in MCU to Driver IC. But DRV10983 IC does not give the any response. This is my circuit. There is nothing changes in Hardware and it works properly. I think issues in programming side to communicate with DRV10983 Driver IC. [image]

Comment: Does your MCU and the driver share ground? If you probe the SCL and SDA pins, how do they look?